# How to give Expression for empty and isNAN function in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

In Jquery.i am migrating below validation from jquery to MVC3 Atrribute.

if ($("#PrevPlanMonths").val() != '' && isNaN($("#PrevPlanMonths").val())) { validationSummary = validationSummary + "! Previous Plan duration is invalid. \n"; isValid = false; }

.NET
public short PreviousPlanDuration { get; set; }

Comment: huh?  is there a question here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you're asking how to get the same validation using an MVC Attribute. If that is what you want, you should try:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage="Previous Plan duration is invalid")]
 [DisplayName("Previous Plan Duration")]
 public short? PreviousPlanDuration {get;set;}
```

And in your View:

```
 <div>
      <div><%: Html.LabelFor(model => Model.PreviousPlanDuration) %><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.PreviousPlanDuration) %></div>
      <div><%: Html.EditorFor(model => Model.PreviousPlanDuration) %></div>
 </div>
```

And when you want to do something with that value, since it is nullable type, use:

```
  PreviousPlanDuration.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read your validation correctly, you are checking that it is a number if the value is not blank right?  Since you have declared your property as a short (integer), when you attempt to model bind, if the value is not an integer, UpdateModel will fail with a datatype mismatch.  As for the required, just decorate the property with the Required attribute.

```
[Required("This field is required")]
public short PreviousPlanDuration { get; set; }
```

Comment: The default value for short is 0 and it will always start with a value. There are a lot of cases where you want to use a Nullable Short to force the user to make a selection.

Comment: Very true - just didn't see the relevance of that discussion to the question posed :)

Comment: The relevance is that the validation may never first, the construction of his model will always assign a default value of 0 to his property. That means with the default value of "0", in most cases you'll bypass the field as being required because the field started with a value. You'll find that if you enter an invalid data type and make a round trip to the server your property will be "0" and thus bypass the "Required" attribute also.